# How to find the public key given only the seed?

Tags: accounts, security

If I have only the seed to an account, how can I find the public key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Java Script**

```
let StellarSdk = require("stellar-sdk");
let keypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret("S...");
console.log(keypair.publicKey());
```

http://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html#.fromSecret

**Go**

```
kp, err := keypair.Parse("S...")
if err != nil {
    fmr.Println("Error", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(kp.Address())
}
```

https://godoc.org/github.com/stellar/go/keypair#Parse